# Use the gulpfiles .tmp-folder

Tags: gulp

Im trying to get my head around Gulp and i am using.
[Yeoman´s webapp](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-gulp-webapp)

Im trying to add some css-files to the project and hopefully get it to end up in the dist/styles-folder.

When adding scss-files to my app/styles-folder and build the project, the files end up in a .tmp-folder. I suppose this is the task that does it:

```
gulp.task('styles', () => {

  return gulp.src('app/styles/*.scss')
    .pipe($.plumber())
    .pipe($.sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe($.sass.sync({
      outputStyle: 'expanded',
      precision: 10,
      includePaths: ['.']
    }).on('error', $.sass.logError))
    .pipe($.autoprefixer({browsers: ['> 1%', 'last 2 versions', 'Firefox ESR']}))
    .pipe($.sourcemaps.write())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('.tmp/styles'))
    .pipe(reload({stream: true}));
});
```

The get compiled from scss to css which should be a good thing but how do I get them from the .tmp-folder tom my dist/index?

I tried: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="./.tmp/styles/style.css">`
It returned a 404 but even so, I cant imagine that this is the right way? Or swill my dist-folder have access to the .tmp-folder? Help appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you want to set the destination folder to `dist`, not `tmp`:

```
 .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/styles'))
```

Comment: Thank you! This makes a lot of sense of course :) Your code indeed outputs the files in the "correct" folder. Im gonna look up the reason for the .tmp-folder.

Comment: Thanks. If my answer was helpful, consider upvoting or accepting it.

Comment: I defenitley will, just thought i´d wait acouple of minutes to see if someone could shed some light on the reason for the .tmp- folder. I upote now and accept soon. Thanks again!

Comment: It's not uncommon to need tmp files to pass work through stages of a pipeline, as not tasks are suitable for passing along in-memory.